# How do I install plugins in Gvim?

Tags: ubuntu, plugins, gvim, r

I want to do R scripts in Gvim. I downloaded a zip file called vim-r-plugin-0.9.6.zip
Then what?

Comment: [Presumed homepage](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2628)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](http://www.lepem.ufc.br/jaa/r-plugin.html)

> 3. Installation

...

> Make a backup of your ~/.vim directory because existing files will be
>   replaced. Please, look at |r-plugin-files| to see the list of files.
>
> 3.2. Operating system specific instructions

...

> 3.2.1. Unix (Linux, OS X, etc.)
>
> Uncompress the archive:

```
unzip vim-r-plugin-*.zip -d ~/.vim
```

> Start Vim and build the tags file for this document (and others that eventually
>   are in the same directory):

```
:helptags ~/.vim/doc
```

Afterwards:

> 3.1. General instructions I

...

> You need to activate plugins and indentation according to 'filetype'. You
>   should have at least the following options in your |vimrc|:

```
set nocompatible
syntax enable
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
```

"Your vimrc" is generally `~/.vimrc` even for gvim, as @garyjohn points out.

Comment: "Your vimrc" is generally ~/.vimrc, even for gvim. The only reason to use ~/.gvimrc is to configure something for only gvim and not vim, and even that can be done within ~/.vimrc.

Comment: ~/.vim ->  No such file or directory

Comment: `mkdir ~/.vim`, then.

Comment: Even had a problem with that earlier today but now no problem. Upvote for simplicity if I could.

Comment: What do you mean with ":helptags ~/.vim/doc"? Answer like I am your greatgreatgrandparent.

Comment: @AWE you start gvim (or vim) and type in (in command/extended mode) `:helptags ~/.vim/doc`. It's not really a necessary step. As I understand it, it creates some bells and whistles for the plugin help files.

Comment: Not sure if anything happens

Comment: If you have a file named `~/.vim/doc/tags` something happened. There is no output when it happens successfully.

Comment: Ok, the general instructions

Comment: Ok the tags file is there but there is no vimrc or gvimrc file.

Comment: No, unless you've made one yourself already, there won't be one. Just make a new file with the four lines above in it and save it as `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: I did, then what? Sorry about this.

Comment: I installed tmux plugin and I think I've done everything right but it still can't run a simple R script.

Comment: This would be the perfect time to start using the plugin. Restart gvim, and open / create-and-save a file with the ending `.R` or `.Rnw` or `.Rd`, and you should have syntax highlighting, R integration and the other stuff the plugin provides.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: I thought I could run the script, but I still can't.

Comment: The documentation link is broken.